# Принцип воспроизведения видео на ютубе

Tags: видео

Помогите разобраться, как ютуб воспроизводит видео.

- Ютуб хранить аудио и видео файлы отдельно?
- Если да, то как видео воспроизводится в браузере? Необходимо
  добавлять тег video и audio отдельно и запускать их отдельно?
- Что лучше, формат mp4 или webm?
- Слышал, что ютуб так же хранит видео обрывками, что за технологию он
  использует, чтобы воспроизводить все эти обрывки как одно целое

Comment: Если взять ссылку из тега `<video>` и открыть видео, то либо ничего не откроется, либо откроется видео в очень плохом качестве. Как тогда работают загрузчики видео с YouTube.

Comment: Открываете хром, заходите в ютуб, открываете dev tools( пкм -> показать код) переходите на вкладку network(сеть) и смотрите реальную ссылку на отрывок в несколько секунд видео в регулярно появляющихся загружаемых данных(будут запросы на контент размером в несколько мегабайт каждые X секунд)

Comment: 1) Для разных устройств и форматов — по-разному; 2) Через MediaSource все фрагменты объединяются в один общий поток; 3) Нет объективно верного ответа; 4) Гуглите про HLS и MPEG-DASH

Comment: 3) mpegts 
4) mpegts